# ElasticSearch: compare dotted version strings

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm looking for a way to save a dotted version as string (e.g "1.2.23") in elastic and then use range query on this field.
e.g

```
{
 "query": {
   "range": {
    "version": {"gte": "1.2.3", "lt": "1.3"}
   }
  }
}
```

I have only 3 components (major, minor, build). I need to be able to determine that

- 1.20.3 > 1.2.3
- 1.02.4 > 1.2.3
- 1.3    > 1.2.3

I thought about the following approaches:

1. Pad with zeros (e.g "1.2.3" -> "000001.000002.000003"). This assumes I know the max length of each component
2. Split into 3 different integer fields (i.e "major", "minor", "build"). Writing queries for this seems to be a pain, but I'd be happy to get suggestions for this.
3. Perhaps some sort of a custom analyser? I saw this: [Elasticsearch analysis plugin for natural sort](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-analysis-naturalsort) which might be a good start.

Any other ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

If you have some latitude in your indexing code to massage those semantic versions into something else, I would suggest to transform each version into a unique integer and then it's very easy to compare those numbers with a single `range` query.

The algorithm is simple:

1. You split the version on dots: `1.2.34` => `1`, `2`, `34`
2. You multiply the major version by 1000000: `1` => `1000000`
3. You multiply the minor version by 1000: `2` => `2000`
4. You sum all three numbers up: `1000000 + 2000 + 34` => `1002034`
5. You store that resulting number into your ES documents and use it to compare versions in `range` queries

Comment: That was my initial approach, but I'm afraid I don't know the constraints on the components. To be specific, I'm talking about iOS version numbers, and as far as I could tell, each component has a max size of MAX_INTEGER. So this won't work: 1.2000000000.1 > 2.1.0. I can't multiple by a bigger number as the maximum number in ES is a long of size 2^64-1. I guess I can't multiple this into a string....

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has added support for version comparison and sort starting from version 7.10.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/version.html